# How to setup a PC under Windows 10 to stream on Twitch using the XBOX app?

Tags: league-of-legends, xbox-one, xbox-network, windows-10, twitch

I am trying to stream myself playing League of Legends using the XBox app on a Windows 10 PC, I heard it was possible but cannot manage to find the right setting. Has anyone else been there ?

Comment: On a side note, why not OBS ?

Comment: The XBox app allows me to easy handle the recording even using Cortana voice commands, but for now I can stream to a TV, a XBox, or even store games on my DVR. I would like to keep the same platform for everything.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately from what I've seen, this feature isn't available yet.

Searching online for it shows some leaked screenshots hinting that it was being worked on, but as of the latest non-insider release (Creators Update), this is currently not in the feature set of Game DVR.

---

If you really want to stream, and don't mind not using Windows Game DVR, then I recommend you to check out OBS, XSplit or Gameshow. Configuration process of all three for twitch are documented on [this page](https://help.twitch.tv/customer/en/portal/articles/792761-how-to-broadcast-pc-games).